# What's the difference between "replace" , "exchange" and "change"?

Tags: word-choice

When I have a problem after purchasing something at the store, I'd like to take it back to the store and change it.  These are two examples. One is that I bought a rug, but it didn't fit the space, so I'd like to change it to something different.  Another is that I bought a space heater, but there's something wrong, so I wanted to change it to a different one.  In these situations, which verb shoud I use?  Or can I use all three verbs interchangeably, saying "I'd like to replace / exchange / change this." or "Could you replace / exchange / change this?"  I looked up the differences on the internet or the dictionary, but still I cannot get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to **exchange** the item you purchased. That is, you want to return to the store the one you bought and have the store give you a new one for one reason or another.

You want the store to **replace** it.

The clearest way to express this in American English is to say to the salesperson or service desk person:

> I'd like to exchange this rug for a larger one (because it's too small for the space I want to put it in). [NB: The reason is optional unless you're asked for a reason.]
>
> I'd like to exchange this space heater for a new one that works. When I tried to use this one that I bought here yesterday, it didn't work. Can we test the new one here before I take it home?

Comment: +1 And when you bring the new rug home you *place* it on the floor, *replacing* the old one with the new one. (Unless the store refuses the exchange, in which case you simply *re-place* the old one!) That does not *change* either the old one or the new one, but it does *change* your room.

Comment: @StoneyB A comment worthy of your wit, but you seem to have forgotten the +1! I'll add my own to make up for it ;)

Comment: @WendiKidd So I did; how embarassing! ... remedied.

Answer (score -1):

Replace means change old ine with new one but should b same item or product.
Change take place when u wear the shirt and asking for another one with that one.
xchange take place when u ask for any shirt in ur hand and asking for another one.